# How do I copy a column's data with reference to another?

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a code to copy the data from 1 column with reference to another column, however it is not including blanks.
For Eg - Column A has 10 values and Column B has 9 values and the last 1 is blank. I need to copy all the data, including the blank and paste it into another sheet. Can anyone please help? Please see the image for example. Column B is dynamic, so Offset doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoJv7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following code?

```
Columns ("A:A").select
Selection.Copy
Columns("B:B)" 
Activesheet.Paste
```

If you want to paste it in another sheet you should refer to the desired sheet instead of ActiveSheet